# Amazon Connect 'Set disconnect flow'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I just noticed that Amazon Connect has a new block called 'Set disconnect flow' and was wondering if it could be used yet or is it still in Beta? I can't seem to find any documentation or release notes.

Comment: I see a "Set hold flow", "Set customer queue flow", and "Set whisper flow", but not a "'Set disconnect flow'". Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @JorgeGarcia. An image can be found at [link](https://imgur.com/a/jBCRYpF)

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect flow is available to voice as well now. We can use this to run post-call surveys, etc.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/set-disconnect-flow.html